# Creating a Dockerfile that includes php, node.js, and php's mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, docker, mysqli

I am trying to create a Dockerfile that defines an environment with php, node.js with express and socket.io, and mysql interoperability.

Currently I have this:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install express
RUN npm install socket.io
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "src/Server.js" ]
```

The problem is, when calling a php function that uses mysqli, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /usr/src/app/src/php/db_connect.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/src/app/src/php/websocketsAPI.php(11): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/src/app/src/php/db_connect.php on line 21
```

I read this is due to a MySQL setting. MySQL isn't installed on this container, so I thought that may be why. If I remember correctly, installing MySQL is not an process that can occur unattended, so I was reluctant to install MySQL using the normal `apt-get` system. I also read that `mysqli` is a php component. I don't need MySQL on this container, except perhaps to solve this current error. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: The idea of installing all of these in one container is exactly what docker is not used for.  Docker is intended to have 1 purpose, so you would normally use a PHP container, a MySQL container and a node container rather than putting them all together.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, particularly in this case. This is for a custom runtime on Google App Engine. I don't want different languages to be different servers (except MySQL, which is a different server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I needed to add this line to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

That makes the Dockerfile this:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
RUN npm install
RUN npm install express
RUN npm install socket.io
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "src/Server.js" ]
```